# State description and rewards in reinforcement learning for card stacking game

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

The challenge is finding the optimal state representation and setting the rewards.

**The game:**  there are n stacks of (playing) cards, which can each be filled up with at most h cards. There is a certain schedule of unique cards which are to stacked and retrieved in a predefined order. For example, card_a must be stacked, card_b must be stacked, card_c must be stacked, card_a must leave the stacks. In order to retrieve a card, it must be at the top of its stack: if it is not, the cards on top must be relocated to other stacks before. The goal of the agent is to process the card arrival and retrieval schedule, needing as little card relocations as possible.

The agent fails to converge using RL or DQN-RL approach, the mean reward over 100 episodes is either oscillating or stuck at a non-optimal point, depending on how whether I also penalize illegal moves or just ignore them and on whether I offer positive reward for each retrieved card or only at the end of the game. My current approach is:

**Rewards:**

- +200 for finishing processing the schedule
- +3 for each retrieved card
- -1 for each relocated card

**State description:**

Option 1) for each stack, there are three informations: the stack height, the index in the departing schedule of the earliest departing card, and the number of cards blocking this earliest departing one. A last, extra column describes the index in the departing schedule of the next three scheduled cards.

The state representation then consists of the flattened array (a vector).

Option 2) The complete configuration of the stacks as a flattened matrix (a vector). The entries are the indexes in the departing schedule (0 if no card is present for that slot, and maxint if the card is not to be retrieved and stays forever in the stack). The vector is then expanded by 3 further entries, representing like in option 1 the indexes in the departing schedule of the next three scheduled cards.

What is an optimal state description for this game? How do I optimally set the rewards?

Answer (score -1):

Nice problem. Your state is fully observed. And the action space is finite and discrete. (Those three criteria also apply to Chess and/or Go, so you can learn a lot from algorithms for those).

You say the DQN does not converge. So some value functions oscillate or explode? Please elaborate on what metrics you track.

Second, with DQN, you can explore the values in different states. Obviously, you have lots of domain knowledge. Go ahead and plot a few interesting states and see what the DQN puts value on. That will learn you where the algorithm diverges from what you expect.

Third, consider to post such questions on Reddit. People discuss these kinds of questions in channels like /r/MLQuestions and /r/learnmachinelearning

Comment: Thanks @RobRomijnders! I did post it on reddit, see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/6faed9/optimal_reinforcement_learning_state/) . What I track is the mean reward over 100 episodes, which should go up as less relocations are needed. The minimum number of relocations is known for toy problems, even for those the mean reward does increase, but not significantly or not enough. That's what lead me to think that my state representations were faulty. I know about Go and chess, it's how I got the idea :-) Do you think the representations are okay as described above?